# A CUDA context was created on a GPU that is not currently debuggable

Tags: cuda, cuda-context

When i start cuda debugging, Nsight return this error:

> A CUDA context was created on a GPU that is not currently debuggable.
>   Breakpoints will be disabled.
>
> Adapter: GeForce GT 720M

This is my system and CUDA information.

Please note that last version of CUDA and Nsight are installed.

I searched this issue and could not find my answer.
Thank you so much.

> ```
> Report Information
>     UnixTime Generated                                                      1490538033
> OS Information
>     Computer Name                                                           DESKTOP-OLFM6NT
>     NetBIOS Name                                                            DESKTOP-OLFM6NT
>     OS Name                                                                 Windows 10 Pro
>     GetVersionEx
>         dwMajorVersion                                                      10
>         dwMinorVersion                                                      0
>         dwBuildNumber                                                       14393
>         dwPlatformId                                                        2
>         wServicePackMajor                                                   0
>         wServicePackMinor                                                   0
>         wSuiteMask                                                          256
>         wProductType                                                        Workstation
>     GetProductInfo                                                          48
>     GetNativeSystemInfo
>         wProcessorArchitecture                                              x64
>         dwPageSize                                                          4096
>         lpMinimumApplicationAddress                                         65536
>         lpMaximumApplicationAddress                                         140737488289791
>         dwActiveProcessorMask                                               15
>         dwNumberOfProcessors                                                4
>         dwAllocationGranularity                                             65536
>         wProcessorLevel                                                     6
>         wProcessorRevision                                                  17665
>     EnumDisplayDevices
>         Display Device
>             DeviceName                                                      \\.\DISPLAY1
>             DeviceString                                                    Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
>             StateFlags                                                      5
>             DeviceID                                                        PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_397817AA&REV_09
>             DeviceKey                                                       \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{A9611CC2-95E1-4DAE-9937-60210AFEDCE0}\0000
>             Monitor
>                 DeviceName                                                  \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0
>                 DeviceString                                                Generic PnP Monitor
>                 StateFlags                                                  3
>                 DeviceID                                                    MONITOR\CMN15B6\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0003
>                 DeviceKey                                                   \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0003
>         Display Device
>             DeviceName                                                      \\.\DISPLAY2
>             DeviceString                                                    Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
>             StateFlags                                                      1
>             DeviceID                                                        PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_397817AA&REV_09
>             DeviceKey                                                       \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{A9611CC2-95E1-4DAE-9937-60210AFEDCE0}\0001
>             Monitor
>                 DeviceName                                                  \\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0
>                 DeviceString                                                Generic PnP Monitor
>                 StateFlags                                                  3
>                 DeviceID                                                    MONITOR\SAM04FD\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0004
>                 DeviceKey                                                   \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0004
>         Display Device
>             DeviceName                                                      \\.\DISPLAY3
>             DeviceString                                                    Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
>             StateFlags                                                      0
>             DeviceID                                                        PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_397817AA&REV_09
>             DeviceKey                                                       \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{A9611CC2-95E1-4DAE-9937-60210AFEDCE0}\0002
>     GlobalMemoryStatusEx
>         dwMemoryLoad                                                        34
>         ullTotalPhys                                                        8486227968
>         ullAvailPhys                                                        5588660224
>         ullTotalPageFile                                                    13854937088
>         ullAvailPageFile                                                    10756182016
>         ullTotalVirtual                                                     140737488224256
>         ullAvailVirtual                                                     140737442308096
>     Processor Information
>         0
>             Name                                                            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
>             Clock speed (MHz)                                               2394
>         1
>             Name                                                            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
>             Clock speed (MHz)                                               2394
>         2
>             Name                                                            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
>             Clock speed (MHz)                                               2394
>         3
>             Name                                                            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
>             Clock speed (MHz)                                               2394
> NvAPI
>     IsMSHybridGraphics                                                      True
>     DisplayDriverVersion
>         Driver Version                                                      37609
>         Changelist                                                          0
>         BuildBranchString                                                   r376_06
>         Default AdapterString                                               GeForce GT 720M
>     DisplayDriverCompileType                                                Release
> NvDebugApi
>     WDDM Devices
>         GPU
>             Name                                                            GeForce GT 720M
>             Architecture                                                    Fermi
>             Architecture Number                                             208
>             Architecture Implementation                                     7
>             Architecture Revision                                           162
>             Number of GPCs                                                  1
>             Number of TPCs                                                  2
>             Number of SMs                                                   2
>             Warps per SM                                                    48
>             Lanes per warp                                                  32
>             Register file size                                              32768
>             Max CTAs per SM                                                 8
>             Max size of shared memory per CTA (bytes)                       49152
>             SM Revision                                                     131073
>             Number of FB PAs                                                6
>             Number of LTs per LTC                                           2
>             RmGpuId                                                         1024
>     RM Devices
> CUDA
>     CUDA Device
>         Name                                                                GeForce GT 720M
>         Driver                                                              WDDM
>         DeviceIndex                                                         0
>         GPU Family                                                          GF117
>         RmGpuId                                                             1024
>         Compute Major                                                       2
>         Compute Minor                                                       1
>         MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK                                               1024
>         MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X                                                     1024
>         MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Y                                                     1024
>         MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Z                                                     64
>         MAX_GRID_DIM_X                                                      65535
>         MAX_GRID_DIM_Y                                                      65535
>         MAX_GRID_DIM_Z                                                      65535
>         MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK                                         49152
>         TOTAL_CONSTANT_MEMORY                                               65536
>         WARP_SIZE                                                           32
>         MAX_PITCH                                                           2147483647
>         MAX_REGISTERS_PER_BLOCK                                             32768
>         CLOCK_RATE                                                          1550000
>         TEXTURE_ALIGNMENT                                                   512
>         GPU_OVERLAP                                                         1
>         MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT                                                2
>         KERNEL_EXEC_TIMEOUT                                                 0
>         INTEGRATED                                                          0
>         CAN_MAP_HOST_MEMORY                                                 1
>         COMPUTE_MODE                                                        0
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_WIDTH                                             65536
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_WIDTH                                             65536
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_HEIGHT                                            65535
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_WIDTH                                             2048
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_HEIGHT                                            2048
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_DEPTH                                             2048
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_WIDTH                                     16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_HEIGHT                                    16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_LAYERS                                    2048
>         SURFACE_ALIGNMENT                                                   512
>         CONCURRENT_KERNELS                                                  1
>         ECC_ENABLED                                                         0
>         PCI_BUS_ID                                                          4
>         PCI_DEVICE_ID                                                       0
>         TCC_DRIVER                                                          0
>         MEMORY_CLOCK_RATE                                                   900000
>         GLOBAL_MEMORY_BUS_WIDTH                                             64
>         L2_CACHE_SIZE                                                       131072
>         MAX_THREADS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR                                      1536
>         ASYNC_ENGINE_COUNT                                                  1
>         UNIFIED_ADDRESSING                                                  1
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LAYERED_WIDTH                                     16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LAYERED_LAYERS                                    2048
>         CAN_TEX2D_GATHER                                                    1
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_GATHER_WIDTH                                      16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_GATHER_HEIGHT                                     16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_WIDTH_ALTERNATE                                   0
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_HEIGHT_ALTERNATE                                  0
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_DEPTH_ALTERNATE                                   0
>         PCI_DOMAIN_ID                                                       0
>         TEXTURE_PITCH_ALIGNMENT                                             32
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_WIDTH                                        16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_LAYERED_WIDTH                                16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_LAYERED_LAYERS                               2046
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_WIDTH                                             65536
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_WIDTH                                             65536
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_HEIGHT                                            32768
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_WIDTH                                             65536
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_HEIGHT                                            32768
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_DEPTH                                             2048
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_LAYERED_WIDTH                                     65536
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_LAYERED_LAYERS                                    2048
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_WIDTH                                     65536
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_HEIGHT                                    32768
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_LAYERS                                    2048
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_WIDTH                                        32768
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_LAYERED_WIDTH                                32768
>         MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_LAYERED_LAYERS                               2046
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LINEAR_WIDTH                                      134217728
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_WIDTH                                      65000
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_HEIGHT                                     65000
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_PITCH                                      1048544
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_MIPMAPPED_WIDTH                                   16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_MIPMAPPED_HEIGHT                                  16384
>         MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_MIPMAPPED_WIDTH                                   16384
>         STREAM_PRIORITIES_SUPPORTED                                         0
>         GLOBAL_L1_CACHE_SUPPORTED                                           1
>         LOCAL_L1_CACHE_SUPPORTED                                            1
>         MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR                                49152
>         MAX_REGISTERS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR                                    32768
>         MANAGED_MEMORY                                                      0
>         MULTI_GPU_BOARD                                                     0
>         MULTI_GPU_BOARD_GROUP_ID                                            0
>         HOST_NATIVE_ATOMIC_SUPPORTED                                        0
>         SINGLE_TO_DOUBLE_PRECISION_PERF_RATIO                               12
>         PAGEABLE_MEMORY_ACCESS                                              0
>         CONCURRENT_MANAGED_ACCESS                                           0
>         COMPUTE_PREEMPTION_SUPPORTED                                        0
>         CAN_USE_HOST_POINTER_FOR_REGISTERED_MEM                             0
>         DISPLAY_NAME                                                        GeForce GT 720M
>         COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MAJOR                                            2
>         COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MINOR                                            1
>         TOTAL_MEMORY                                                        2147483648
>         RAM_TYPE                                                            7
>         RAM_LOCATION                                                        1
>         GPU_PCI_DEVICE_ID                                                   289411294
>         GPU_PCI_SUB_SYSTEM_ID                                               939530154
>         GPU_PCI_REVISION_ID                                                 161
>         GPU_PCI_EXT_DEVICE_ID                                               4416
>         GPU_PCI_EXT_GEN                                                     1
>         GPU_PCI_EXT_GPU_GEN                                                 1
>         GPU_PCI_EXT_GPU_LINK_RATE                                           5000
>         GPU_PCI_EXT_GPU_LINK_WIDTH                                          8
>         GPU_PCI_EXT_DOWNSTREAM_LINK_RATE                                    5000
>         GPU_PCI_EXT_DOWNSTREAM_LINK_WIDTH                                   4
> ```

Comment: What you did to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your GT 720m is a compute capability 2.1 device (see [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)).

Attempting to debug CUDA code (e.g. set breakpoints) on a GPU that is also supporting (hosting) a display requires a compute capability 3.5 or higher device, to support *preemption*.

Your device does not meet that requirement, so because your GPU is hosting your laptop display, it cannot be used to set breakpoints in CUDA code.

Also note that the latest version of Nsight VSE (5.2 at this time) has [officially dropped support](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements) for Fermi GPUs (yours is a Fermi GPU):

> Note: Fermi family GPUs, and older families, are no longer supported with Nsight™ Visual Studio Edition 5.2 or better.

Comment: I have the sam graphic card. What should i do now?

Comment: Install Nsight 5.1 could help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try falling back to an older version of Nsight.

I recently ran into this problem and installing an older version helped.